# NaN values in normal point

Tags: c++, computer-vision, nan, point-cloud-library, normals

I'm having a problem verifying the value contained in the coordinates of the normal point. Initially I estimate the normal of my cloud and when I'll check the xyz coordinates of the normal it's returned nan.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

// Object for normal estimation.
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normalEstimation;
normalEstimation.setInputCloud(cloud);
// For every point, use all neighbors in a radius of 3cm.
normalEstimation.setRadiusSearch(0.03);
// A kd-tree is a data structure that makes searches efficient. More about it later.
// The normal estimation object will use it to find nearest neighbors.
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr kdtree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
normalEstimation.setSearchMethod(kdtree);

// Calculate the normals.
normalEstimation.compute(*normals);

for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); i++){
  std::cout << "x: " << cloud->points[i].x <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "normal x: " << normals->points[i].normal_x <<std::endl; //-nan here
}
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: Read [here about NaN](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/): `The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable values for floating-point elements, such as the square root of negative numbers or the result of 0/0.` So there will be malformed calculation anywhere, but you didn't provide that part of code of your method `compute`.

Comment: @AndreKampling PCL is a trusted standard library. There is no need for OP to provide the implementation of the *library* itself; his problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Thank you didn't know PCL, he didn't write something about it and just from code I didn't know...

Comment: any computation can fail. I could imagine that the normal will have a NaN when all points in your point cloud are lying eg along a single line (or on a plane).

Comment: You might have duplicate points in your dataset that will cause the normal computation to fail. Try clean the data first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with your input point cloud. Make sure your point cloud is not **a flat plane** and make sure you don't have **duplicate points**. What was ailing me was the **search radius**. Try playing with that too.

I just encountered a similar problem with very similar code. The comments were very helpful, thanks. This is probably too late, but it might still help somebody.